# imageView clickable and scrollable

Tags: android, scroll, imageview, touch

i want to be able to click and scroll an Image View but it happened that whenever i touch the Image View and perform the "action move" it does not scroll but perform a "click event" instead!
I want to be able to do both meaning when i touch and move it should scroll but when i just touch then it should perform the click!
Thanks in advance

This is what i have done

```
    ImageView ivUser = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivUser);
    ivUser.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(StoryDetails.this, ProfileView.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", usersid);
            Log.d("ivUser attempt", usersid);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

i just implemented the "onTouch listener" like the code below but i don't have any idea about what to do next!

```
    ivPost.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                Log.d("ACTION_DOWN", "ACTION_DOWN");
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:{
                Log.d("ACTION_MOVE", "ACTION_MOVE");
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:{
                Log.d("LENGTH_LONG!", "LENGTH_LONG");
                break;
            }
            }
            return true;
        }
   });
```

Comment: you are using setonclicklistener which is trigered when the imageview is clicked..so what was your initial logic.. brb with your answer got to answer some home calls

Comment: i just implemented the "onTouch listener" like the code below but i don't have any idea about what to do next!

Comment: Sir, with deep respect, first of all that's onClick listener.. but ima put an answer shortly..

Comment: yea but you are already on point sir.. just move the image your MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE case

Comment: if the answer helped you, you can always accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "image clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    image.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
            switch (arg1.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
                // where user releases finger 
                if(!moved){
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), String.valueOf(moved), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    image.performClick(); // you use this if you badly need the onclick listener
                    // but you can replace and put your onclick listener codes directly here
                }
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                moved = true;
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "image is moving", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), String.valueOf(moved), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // scroll your stuff here, meaning put the scrolling codes here
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:                   
                //this is where touch is trigered, you can call the performclick function here                   
                // this will always b called first but we can do some boolean magic here..
                moved = false;
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

your boolean should be a global variable `private boolean moved; // this is the boolean`

Comment: i also noticed that it always call the "action_down" before the "action_move"!

Comment: yea Sir, its trigered when the touch is dispatched on the view.. yea what about your scroll code how you want it..@Icefall007

Comment: i have a linear layout that contains an Image View and some Text Views but the image View takes almost the whole screen so i want o be able to perform to event on that image View: 1) "action_move" to be able to scroll down n view the text Views and 2) "action_down" to be able to perform-click. I hope you understand What i am saying!

Comment: you mean your imageview takes up the whole space -but that cant be right because it might be used on tablets which is a bigger screen and might fit good, but the testing device is a lil smaller or giving you that outcome but i get that side of the story, well the other side of it which is scrolling i do not really get it. but you can use a viewflipper that will hide the textview and show the image and whiles you catch the action_move you flip to the textview in an animating way, that might also build your ui and if its action_up is triggerd with moved being false do your click @Icefall007

Comment: or please sir give me an example like scenario so i get you properly okay.. because you can also go with scrollview..@Icefall007